# How to fetch data by a conditional query(left join/right join/inner join/ multi select, ... or) from multi table

Tags: mysql, if-statement, conditional-statements

I have a problem with conditional query and can't solve that and I need your help.
I use mysql with innodb and I have some tables like bellow.

table1:
---------------------- uers_type_1 ----------------------

```
user_id int(11) primary auto_increment
firstname varchar(15)
lastname varchar(20)
.
.
.
```

table 2:
---------------------- uers_type_2 ----------------------

```
user_id int(11) primary auto_increment
firstname varchar(15)
lastname varchar(20)
.
.
.
```

table 3: 
---------------------- user_request ----------------------

```
request_id int(11) primary auto_increment
user_type enum("ut1","ut2")
user_id int(11)
request text
```

Now I need a query to fetch something like this:
user request data with user first name and last name from users type tables

Result:

```
-----------------------------------------------
- firstName - lastName - request_id - request -
-----------------------------------------------
- Robert    - De Niro  - 10         - some request.
- Will      - Smith    - 93         - some request.
.
.
.
```

My query something like this but it's not work

```
SELECT r.request_id , r.request, (
 execute(
  concat('select u.first_name AS firstName, u.lastname AS lastName from ', 
           (SELECT CASE r.user_type WHEN 'ut1' 
           THEN 'uers_type_1' WHEN 'ut2' THEN 'uers_type_2' END), 
           ' u WHERE u.user_id = ', r.user_id, ''
  )
 )
)
FROM `user_request` r
WHERE 1
```

Answer (score 1):

I got a solution for your problem,

```
select user_request.r_id , user_request.request,
(select Case user_request.user_type when 'u1' then user_type_1.fistname else user_type_2.firstname end ) as name
from user_request 
left JOIN user_type_1 on user_request.user_id = user_type_1.id and user_request.user_type = 'u1' 
left JOIN user_type_2 on user_request.user_id = user_type_2.id and user_request.user_type = 'u2'
```

the point is that :
try to point both tables in the query using left join and then in your select options choose where it should be used for fetching the data.

```
(select Case user_request.user_type when 'u1' then user_type_1.firstname else user_type_2.firstname end ) as name,
(select Case user_request.user_type when 'u1' then user_type_1.lastname else user_type_2.lastname end ) as family
```

hope that help you.

Comment: Thank you dear Sir1. your solution is good and i used that. but is a big problem in your solution. my main tables have a lot of data and your solution is a little slow. specially in first execute.
i test this for just 4 row and It took 1.8365 seconds and the next execute took 0.4231 seconds for same rows.

Have you any other solution?

Comment: Use explain plans and look if indexes are being used. You may need to ask a new question for performance tuning. In such a question knowing what indexes exist is essential and so is the query and the explain plan. Use text not images of that information.

Comment: @Used_By_Already Yes, that is a kind of performance issue and should be considered separately, thank you for note that

Answer (score 1):

Having 2 user tables is going to perplex and frustrate you. While I don't know why you have them if it is possible consider moving them into to a single table. In any case, you can produce a single view of the user information by using a `UNION ALL` query such as this:

```
  SELECT
        'ut1' AS user_type
      , user_id
      , firstname
      , lastname
  FROM user_type_1
  UNION ALL
  SELECT
        'ut2' AS user_type
      , user_id
      , firstname
      , lastname
  FROM user_type_2
  ;
```

That query might literally be used to create a `view` but that it is optional. That `UNION ALL` approach can be used as a  `derived table` subquery in a query like the following. Notice how this simplifies access to the name columns.

```
  SELECT
        user_request.r_id
      , user_request.request
      , u.firstname                ## simple to access
      , u.lastname                 ## simple to access
  FROM user_request AS ur
  INNER JOIN (
        SELECT
              'ut1' AS user_type
            , user_id
            , firstname
            , lastname
        FROM user_type_1
        UNION ALL
        SELECT
              'ut2' AS user_type
            , user_id
            , firstname
            , lastname
        FROM user_type_2
  ) AS u ON ur.user_type = u.user_type
        AND ur.user_id = u.user_id
  ;
```

Another alternative is to use 2 left joins, one for each user table and include the `user_type` into each join as a condition of the join. Note here the names can be NULL due the way the left joins will work, so you can overcome that by seing `COALESCE()` or `IFNULL()`

```
  SELECT
        ur.r_id
      , ur.request
      , COALESCE(ut1.fistname,ut2.firstname) firstname
      , COALESCE(ut1.lastname,ut2.lastname) lastname
  FROM user_request as ur
  LEFT JOIN user_type_1 as ut1 ON ur.user_id = ut1.id
        AND ur.user_type = 'ut1'
  LEFT JOIN user_type_2 as ut2 ON ur.user_id = ut2.id
        AND ur.user_type = 'ut2'
  ;
```

---

If you should choose to create a view, e.g.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW users_all_v
AS
  SELECT
        'ut1' AS user_type
      , user_id
      , firstname
      , lastname
  FROM user_type_1
  UNION ALL
  SELECT
        'ut2' AS user_type
      , user_id
      , firstname
      , lastname
  FROM user_type_2
  ;
```

Then subsequent queries become easier to assemble e.g.

```
  SELECT
        user_request.r_id
      , user_request.request
      , u.firstname                ## simple to access
      , u.lastname                 ## simple to access
  FROM user_request AS ur
  INNER JOIN users_all_v AS u ON ur.user_type = u.user_type
        AND ur.user_id = u.user_id
  ;
```

**AND** even if you do one day combine those 2 user tables into 1, you can just adjust that view and existing queries will not be broken.

Comment: Thank you dear friend. your solution is good, but use from view or use from one table for all users not optimal in this case.
and i know it's better to all user tables be mixed in one table but in this case difference between users data is too much, and memory overhead is high if i join those table in one table, because each table have a lot of users and very different data column and many cells should to be empty.

Comment: I understand the difficulties of such things. But using a view of a few common columns `will be just as efficient` as using 2 left joins. And, your subsequent queries will be simpler to write. DO NOT use order by in the view, that is a common mistake. Views are just stored queries.